# When does a Smart contract get executed/called

Tags: contract-development, contract-deployment

I'm fairly new to Ethereum and Smart Contracts.
After i publish a Smart Contract on the Chain, on what ways or how will it be executed? Who can call my Smart Contract? And under what conditions?
I'm currently a bit confused about the lifecycle of a smart contract. Would be awesome if you could provide me some Information or Ressource for that.

Thank You

Answer (score 1):

There are two kinds of accounts, Externally Owned Accounts (EOA) and contacts.

Both types have an address. An EOA has a private key for signing transactions. A contract has no private key and cannot sign a transaction. It has code that tells it what is *must* do and a storage namespace where it can store state data.

All transactions are kicked off by someone or something signing a transaction. That transaction may be addressed to a contract. In that case, it will usually contain additional data to indicate the function to invoke and arguments to pass in.

When such a transaction is mined, the code in the contract function is executed by each node to evaluate how that transaction updates the contract's internal state.

Hope it helps.